# How to unterupt /etc/acpi/lid.sh when laptop lid is open?

Tags: debian, laptop, acpi

## Version 1

*Go directly to version 2 below*

On Debian, I followed [this guide](https://mensfeld.pl/2018/08/ubuntu-18-04-disable-screen-on-lid-close/) to define a behavior when my laptop’s lid is closed.

So I made the following modifications :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Disable sleep on lead (do noting)
echo 'HandleLidSwitch=ignore' | tee --append /etc/systemd/logind.conf
echo 'HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore' | tee --append /etc/systemd/logind.conf
sudo service systemd-logind restart


# Disable screen on lid close/etc/acpi/events
mkdir -r /etc/acpi/events
echo 'event=button/lid.*' | tee --append /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
echo 'action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh' | tee --append /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
# The lid.sh should be in the same directory
mv ./lid.sh /etc/acpi/lid.sh
chmod +x /etc/acpi/lid.sh

# Restarting service to take effect
/etc/init.d/acpid restart
```

Then I create the `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` which is activated each time I close the lid instead of the default behavior.

The `lid.sh` is the following one:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Lid closing event script


grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        echo close>>/tmp/screen.lid
     # main user
    USER=fauve
    # Remaining percent of battry
    REMAININGBAT=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep percentage | sed "s/ *percentage: *\(.*\)%/\1/")

    # Test battry remaining percentage
    if [ $REMAININGBAT -gt 10 ]; then
        # If the percentage is higher than 10
        TIMEBEFORELOCK="1m"
        TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION="9m"
        TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN="5 minutes"
    else
        # If the percentage is less than 10
        TIMEBEFORELOCK="1m"
        TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION="2m"
        TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN="4 minutes"
    fi

    # Do noting a ${TIMEBEFORELOCK} time
    # In case if a quick shifting from a room to another
    echo "$(date): Waiting ${TIMEBEFORELOCK} before lock"
    sleep ${TIMEBEFORELOCK}

    # set screensaver for ${TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION} time
    echo "$(date): Lock now"
    su -c  "DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/$USER/.local/bin/screenlock" - $USER &
    echo "$(date): Waiting ${TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION} before suspension"
    sleep ${TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION}

    # Set a wake up at given time
    echo "$(date): Seting time before waking up to ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN}"
    echo `date '+%s' -d "+ ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN}"` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm

    # Suspend for ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN} time
    echo "$(date): Starting suspention for ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN}"
    systemctl suspend
    echo "$(date): Wake up"

    # Wait 5s to ensure the next command will take effect
    sleep 5s

    # shutdown
    #echo "$(date): Shutdown"
    #shutdown +0
fi
grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo open>>/tmp/screen.lid
fi
```

This script should keep going as long as I am not opening the lid. But it NECESSARY should be interrupted when the lid is open (if the last line is not yet reached).

So, how to tell ACPI to interrupt when I open the lid?

---

## Version 2

So, I update my script as below :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Lid closing event script

PIDFILE=/tmp/lidpid

grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo $$ > $PIDFILE
    echo "$(date) close">>/tmp/screen.lid
     # main user
    USER=fauve
    # Remaining percent of battry
    REMAININGBAT=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep percentage | sed "s/ *percentage: *\(.*\)%/\1/")

    # Test battry remaining percentage
    if [ $REMAININGBAT -gt 10 ]; then
        # If the percentage is higher than 10
        TIMEBEFORELOCK="1m"
        TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION="9m"
        TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN="5 minutes"
    else
        # If the percentage is less than 10
        TIMEBEFORELOCK="1m"
        TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION="2m"
        TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN="4 minutes"
    fi

    # Do noting a ${TIMEBEFORELOCK} time
    # In case if a quick shifting from a room to another
    echo "$(date): Waiting ${TIMEBEFORELOCK} before lock"
    sleep ${TIMEBEFORELOCK}

    # set screensaver for ${TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION} time
    echo "$(date): Lock now"
    su -c  "DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/$USER/.local/bin/screenlock" - $USER &
    echo "$(date): Waiting ${TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION} before suspension"
    sleep ${TIMEBEFORESUSPENSION}

    # Set a wake up at given time
    echo "$(date): Seting time before waking up to ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN}"
    echo `date '+%s' -d "+ ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN}"` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm

    # Suspend for ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN} time
    echo "$(date): Starting suspention for ${TIMEBEFORESHUTDOWN}"
    systemctl suspend
    echo "$(date): Wake up"

    # Wait 5s to ensure the next command will take effect
    sleep 5s

    echo "Going to shutdown"
    # shutdown
    #echo "$(date): Shutdown"
    shutdown +0
fi


# Wait 5s to ensure the next command will take effect
sleep 5s
grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo "$(date) open">>/tmp/screen.lid
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ] ; then
        kill -9 $(cat $PIDFILE)
    fi
fi
```

But now, the problem is ACPI have some trouble to detect lid opening. When I close and open the lid, then I go to `/tmp/screen.lid` I find “close” mark, but I didn’t find “open” mark. “Open” mark comes later and it seems random.

Comment: You need to add your entire script if you expect anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: No mater, I modify it to make my exact situation. I thank in the beginning I should bring a Minimal Work Example, that’s why I focus on the essential.

Comment: I just make some tests, so the content of `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` have absolutely no incidence on the process. ACPI just try to keep going the process however the lip is opened. That’s why I ask how to tel ACPI completely break the script immediately after the lip opening.

Comment: Well, there are multiple problems with your script. The first problem I see is that you are not checking for the state of the lid in `/proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state` as they do in the guide. Your script **will** get triggered on both open and close actions, you'll need to add checks yourself. Second, you need some mechanism to stop the second running instance of your script when opening the lid.

Comment: @mashuptwice you’re absolutely right. I better understand now how this script works. In the beginning I thank it’s only called when the lid is opened. Now, I modify it to put his wool old content in a condition.

Comment: @mashuptwice in the Second problem you talk about, is it a good idea to store a pid with someting like `echo $$ > /tmp/lidclosepid` in the first statement; then in every lid opening I do a `if [ -e /tmp/lidclosepid ] ; then kill -9 $(echo /tmp/lidclosepid) fi` ?

Comment: this is exactly how I've done it in the past. Works like a charm. Please add your finished script as an answer to make it easier for others with the same problem to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are multiple problems with your script.

The first problem I see is that you are not checking for the state of the lid in /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state as they do in the guide. Your script will get triggered on both open and close actions, you'll need to add checks yourself.

Second, you need some mechanism to stop the already running instance of your script when opening the lid.